# Prevent child elements from picking up click handler

Tags: jquery, click

I have a bunch of divs laid out on a page:

```js
singleItem: function() {
    $('.grid-item').on('click', function(e) {
      // do a bunch of stuff
      $('.grid-item').removeClass('grid-item--selected');
      $(this).addClass('grid-item--selected');
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```html
<div class="grid-item grid-item--selected" data-category="month-5 month-6 month-11 month-12" style="position: absolute; left: 755px; top: 0px;">
  <div class="grid-img">
    <a href="/blah/blah/blah">
      <img src="//someimg.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item--action">
    <h4 class="grid-copy grid-action">
      Product Item
    </h4>
    <a href="/blah/blah.blah">
      <button class="grid-item--action__btn" data-attr="28971">Action!</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <a class="grid-item--corner" href="/blah/blah/blah"></a>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the div, classes are applied and some items are shuffled around via Packery. However, If I attach click events to the child elements:

```js
analyticsLinks: function() {
  $('a button.grid-item--action__btn').on('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // make SC call
  });
  $('a.grid-item--corner').on('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // make SC call
  });
}
```

... the click event from the parent $('.grid-item') is activated. How do I prevent the click event attached to the parent ('.grid-item') from being applied to the child elements $('a button.grid-item--action__btn') and $('a.grid-item--corner')?

Comment: If you use the snippet editor, make the code [mcve]

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid; you cannot have nested clickable elements. You need to move the `button` outside of the `a`, or remove it completely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following this whole situation. It sounds like you have a box, and you don't want the children to trigger the event on the parent but the parent is still clickable.

I think you want to do something like:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', e => {
  if (e.target === this) {
    console.log('I definitely clicked `.parent`.)
  } else {
    console.log('I clicked a child of it.
  }
});
```

If I'm misunderstanding, sorry.

Comment: Partially. When the child elements are clicked (for example, $('a.grid-item--corner')) - the parent click event is getting fired. That's what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: This would allow for that, but the stopPropagation should work as well. You should definitely not have a button in an `<a>`. That can be throwing things off.

Comment: With `currentTarget` it would always be true. I'm using target because it's whatever was actually clicked.

Comment: Also, `this` in jQuery is `e.currentTarget`.